# .Net Core Console App Referenced Project FileNotFound Error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

I have a .net core Console app (netcoreapp2.2) that has a project reference to a .net standard Library project (netstandard2.0). The solution builds successfully but when I try to instantiate a class from the library I get the following:

`Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in Console.dll. An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Console.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Library, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.`

When I remove the project reference and add a dependency reference directly to the debug Library.dll file manually, the project builds and runs normally.

**Edit**: It is important to note also that when I look in `Console\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2`, the Library.dll and Library.pdb files are present.

Interestingly, if I create a new Library2 project with a different name but copy all of the files from Library into it and change them to the Library2 namespace, the project builds and runs successfully. I could do this as a last resort but would like to understand what's going on.

I don't see anything in either of the .csproj files that would indicate that they would act differently.

Comment: Did you check the `copyToOutPut` directly is set to `Always` from the properties?

Comment: are other projects being referenced in console app, which are also referencing library?

Comment: @ZubaerNaseem, yes there is another ConsoleApp that references Library but it is also targetting netcoreapp2.2. Is there anything else here that I should consider?

Comment: @HariHaran, I have an appsettings.json and a nlog.config in the Console app that are set to 'Copy if newer'. All other files are set to 'Do not copy'.

Comment: @BenRipley delete bin and obj folder of the all the projects referencing library + make sure all projects are using same version of library. I have faced similar issue if .net version is changed without deleting bin and obj.

Comment: @ZubaerNaseem, Thanks I tried deleting bin/obj on all projects in the sln but still the same problem. All of my library projects are netstandard2.0 and all console projects are netcoreapp2.2